# How do I securely save a variable not affected by render?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am trying to save a variable from the user collection to the client so that I can use it, but I don't want the client to be able to change the variable. How do I achieve this?

Currently I have this, but it keeps switching on and off cause it doesn't always get the variable from the collection while rendering:

```
function AdminMenu() {
    const user = useTracker(() => Meteor.user());
    
    if (user.admin) {
        return (
            <div>isAdmin</div>
        );
    } else {
        return (<div/>);
    }
}
```

I can get it to work the way I want like this, but I am afraid that the client is able to edit the variable:

```
let isAdmin = false;

function AdminMenu() {
    const user = useTracker(() => Meteor.user());
    
    if (user.admin) {
        isAdmin = true;
    }
    
    if (isAdmin) {
        return (
            <div>isAdmin</div>
        );
    } else {
        return (<div/>);
    }
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The nature of the client is that it is insecure and so editing the variable is always possible. What matters is that you only trust the code executed on the server and never trust data supplied by the client without validation.

As far as the variable switching, this is due to the fact that the subscription isn't ready yet. Generally speaking you'll want to wait for any subscription that your data relies on to be ready before you render sections of the component that rely on that data.

Comment: Ahh yes, so I create a method on the server to check if a user is admin or not. That makes sense. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Hmm well, I can't seem to get that to work since there's a delay with calling methods, but currently I am only sending the user.admin to the user that has the value and with the subscription.ready() function it seems to work. Is the client able to change the value of or add to the user collection?

Comment: You can get the ready state from the subscription handle.

Comment: If you want, feel free to stop by the Meteor Community Slack workspace and we can discuss more strategies to solve this problem  https://meteor-community.slack.com/join/shared_invite/enQtODA0NTU2Nzk5MTA3LWY5NGMxMWRjZDgzYWMyMTEyYTQ3MTcwZmU2YjM5MTY3MjJkZjQ0NWRjOGZlYmIxZjFlYTA5Mjg4OTk3ODRiOTc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the change is that the subscription isn't ready when the component first renders, but once it is ready tracker will cause the template to rerender and show the new state. To fix this you'll need to subscribe within your use tracker hook and only render once the subscription becomes ready. Give this a try.

```
function AdminMenu() {
  const { user, ready } = useTracker(() => ({
    user: Meteor.user(),
    ready: Meteor.subscribe('your-subscription-name').ready();
  }));
  
  if (ready && user.admin) {
      return (
          <div>isAdmin</div>
      );
  } else {
      return (<div/>);
  }
}
```

There is another method of dealing with this that is a bit more complex so I won't detail it here, but see my comment above and come join the Meteor Community Slack and I'm more than happy to help you further if you'd like.